# Why I get an error while working on a slice of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a filtered dataframe called df_final, I wanted two have additional tabs. For tab 2, I create a new column, then do filterig on that column and save it, then delete the created column and save it as tab 1. Here is the code:

```
  df_final = df.query(query)
  df_final["Duplicate"] = df_final.duplicated(subset=['DR/ER#'])
  df_tab2 = df_final.loc[df_final['Duplicate']== True]
  df_tab1 = df_final.drop(columns = ['Duplicate', 'DR/ER#'])
  df_tab1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'DR ER')
  df_tab2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'DR ER duplicates')
```

but I get this **Error**.

```
<ipython-input-6-4e0fc04c4f3a>:46: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_final["Duplicate"] = df_final.duplicated(subset=['DR/ER#'])
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Did you `See the caveats in the documentation:...` as the message suggested? Try searching SO with the error message, you should get plenty of information.

Comment: Did you try using the method suggested in the error message? - `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: I didn;t get the method, for which I need to do that? I searched the method but didn't get  anything on how it works

Answer (score 1):

*df_final* is actually a **view** of the original DataFrame
(sharing its data buffer), so you cannot alter it.

If you want to alter *df_final*, create it as a **new** DataFrame (with its
own data buffer). To do it, run e.g.:

```
df_final = df.query(query).copy()
```

and the "link" to the original DataFrame will no longer exist.